Cartoon Movie that aired between 2000 and 2009 and looks like Danny Phantom
I've done a lot of searches and want to watch this movie again, but can't find its name. It aired on a kids channel like Nickelodeon or Cartoon Network.
It is a cartoon style movie about a boy (that looks like Danny Phantom as I recall) living in a farm. And he had this Stinky Something (I would guess socks) passed generation through generation. Then a spaceship comes crashing in the grains silo. A princess asks for his help and he is carried to some sort of school in space with a dome over it.
He makes some friends and stuff (I don't really recall the middle of the movie). And at the end He is saving a girl from being sucked into a black hole.

This is not a movie. It's an episode of Fairly Odd Parents called Crash Nebula (Season 5, episode 22) which is basically the origin story of the titular superhero. From Wikia:

One day, while "doing his chores" (just laying around reading comic books) Sprig sees a giant space ship appear [on his family farm]. Out runs a butterfly-esque creature, being chased down by bugdroids. Leaping into action, Sprig saves the creature, who thanks him and introduces herself as Princess Galaxandra. In return for his heroism, she gives him a free scholarship to the [glass-domed] Celestial Academy. Sprig happily accepts. When his family hears of it, his parents happily congratulate him, and his father gives him the family manure.

Sprig\Crash saves a girl from being sucked into a vortex near the end. Here's the entire episode:



